# Show Modal Dialog Just in Current Area Grid.Colum/Grid.Row

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

I am learning modal dialog from this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36516/WPF-Modal-Dialog, but, is there possible to show that modal dialog just blocking in area `Grid.Column`/`Grid.Rows` only, and beside that, another `Grid.Column`/`Grid.Rows` still accessible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a [Modal Dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) is(emphasis mine):

> In user interface design, a modal window is a child window that **requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating the parent application**, thus preventing the workflow on the application main window. Modal windows are often called heavy windows or modal dialogs because the window is often used to display a dialog box.

Thus the answer to your question is no if you want a Modal Dialog box. If you just want to block a certain section of your Grid, just load your Dialog as an UserControl over the section you want to prevent from being used. You will still be able to access the rest of your application then.

Comment: Thanks. now i am using that ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably currently overlaying the complete grid with the modal dialog:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ModalDialogParent">
        ...
    </Grid>

    <controls:ModalDialog x:Name="ModalDialog" />
</Grid>
```

Instead, it *should* work¹ to just fix the modal dialog into a specific portion of your parent grid, by putting it *inside* the grid and specifying its position:

```
<Grid x:Name="ModalDialogParent">
    ...

    <controls:ModalDialog x:Name="ModalDialog"
                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

---

¹ I'm not familiar with the modal dialog code you linked to, I just quickly glanced over it right now.

Comment: Ya, i can try this way to fix the modal dialog into a specific position what i want, but still, another Grid.Rows / Grid.Column was disabled too. may be my question not clear enough, but what i want is how to enable another Grid.Column too? Thanks.